# Formatting data in the axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, c3.js

I am implementing a stacked chart using nvd3. One problem I am having is formatting the x data with the x-axis label

The x-axis data will in the form of `year.week`. But, I need the data to be shown at label as year | week. How can I format this data as I want to?

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
        //If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered
        .reduceXTicks(false)
        //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
        .rotateLabels(0)    
        //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode  
        .showControls(false) 
        //Distance between each group of bars  
        .groupSpacing(0.1)
        .stacked(true);

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(exampleData()).call(chart);
    console.log(exampleData()[0]);
    d3.select('#chart2 svg').datum(exampleData()).call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

Comment: Try to make a fiddle with sample data, then we could do something on it. Try this once in `chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));` replace with your own callback like this `chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d){ //write your formatting code and return });`

Comment: Show us what you're trying to do. You can use this Fiddle as a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0h8sh7am/13/